# How to clean Aerosmith's discography by looping over agrepl and replacing matches with a vector?

Tags: r, loops, indexing, gsub

I've scraped some data from a discography website to make an infographic of a Aerosmith's song category with.  The dataset has a song variable that has many random/unwanted characters, some punctuation and some rows have more than one song in the column.

I'm trying, without getting anywhere, to loop over the songs with vector 'y', find approximate matches and replace the match with value 'y'.  I'm not sure if a for loop is the best approach, and basically I'm at a standstill.

The code below is a reproducible dataset and the code I'm using to search and replace.

```
y <- c('Eat the Rich','Cry\'n','Dream On','Crazy')

set.seed(123)

alpha <- data_frame(
 songs= paste0(sample(c('walkthisway','adfkbjf','dudelookslikealady','cryn','eattherich'),100,replace=T),sample(c('aadfa','aghnds','crazy','wwrrsdg'),100,replace=T)),

 album=sample(c('Toys in the Attic','Get a Grip','Greatest Hits'),100,replace=T))

alpha %>% head()
```

This is the progress I've made with code, it seems to work when the vector 'y' contains only 1 value.

```
alpha[[i]][agrepl(y,alpha[[i]])] <- y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it takes :-)

```
# Remove special characters
# In this case " " and "'"
foo <- gsub(" |'", "" , y)
# Transform to lower case
foo <- tolower(foo)

for(i in foo) {
    # Get original song name
    bar <- y[which(foo == i)]
    # Find matches and replace with original song
    alpha$songs[grep(i, alpha$songs)] <- bar
}
```

Comment: this works great. Solutions are always easier than expected. I thank you, and Aerosmith thanks you.

Comment: @elliot if it solved your problem you can accept my answer